# Spring MVC: CannotLoadBeanClassException for bean in classpath resource

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat7

My set up is as follows:

- Tomcat 7
- Spring MVC 3.0.6
- Eclipse Indigo

File structur looks like this

```
src
    - main
      - java
      - resources
        - mdp-servlet.xml
        - mdp-service.xml
      - webapp
        - WEB-INF
          - web.xml
    - test
```

mdp-servlet.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="ch.hszt.mdp.web" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping" /> 

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter" />


     <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

mdp-service.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="userService" class="ch.hszt.mdp.service.UserServiceImpl" />

</beans>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

    <!-- Needed to see file mdp-service.xml -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:mdp-service.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <display-name>testing</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mdp</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mdp</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Sourcefolder:

- src/main/java
- src/main/resources
- src/test/java

This is the error message I get when I try to start the project with Tomcat within eclipse

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mdp-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mdp-servlet.xml]
```

Has anyone an idea to fix this?

Thx a lot!

Comment: yes it does...if I take the files from resources and put them into web-inf everything works fine

Comment: From `resources`? It shouldn't have even tried to load the bean if the config file didn't exist, but ok.

Comment: now im getting a different error...havent changed anything...see updated post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the solution

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>mdp</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>classpath:mdp-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mdp</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```